# Форма регистрации и Логина на одной странице

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

```
<body>
    <div id="bar">
        <div style="margin:auto;width:60%;">
            <img src="/icons/logo.png" style="height:110px;margin-top:-5px;float:left">
            <div class="But_fam"> BUT family</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">

    <div id="block2">
        <img src="/icons/123.png" id="but">
        <p>Станьте частью семьи Bucheon!
    </div>
    <div id="block1">
        <div class="main">  
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk" aria-hidden="true">

        <!--SIGN UP FORM-->
        <div class="signup">
       
            <form method="post">
            <label for="chk" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#ffb308">Sign up</label>
                <div style="padding-left:9%;padding-right:9%">
                    <input style="width:39%;white-space: nowrap;float:left;" value="<?php echo $first_name ?>" required="" name="first_name" type="text" id="text" placeholder="First name"> &nbsp
                    <input style="width:39%;white-space: nowrap;float:left;margin-left:4%" value="<?php echo $last_name ?>" required="" name="last_name" type="text" id="text" placeholder="Last name"><br><br>
                </div>
                    <span style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;text-align:center;justify-content:center;display:flex;color:white">Gender:</span>
                    <select name="gender" style="margin:auto; display:flex;">
                        <option><?php echo $gender ?></option>
                        <option>Male</option>
                        <option>Female</option>
                    </select>
            
                    <input style="margin:auto;margin-top:10px;" value="<?php echo $email ?>" name="email" required="" type="text" id="text" placeholder="Email"><br>
                    
                    <input style="margin:auto;margin-top:-10px;" name="password" type="password" id="text" required=""  placeholder="Password"><br>
                    <input style="margin:auto;margin-top:-10px;" name="password2" type="password" id="text" required="" placeholder="Retype Password">

                    <button type="submit" id="button1" value="Sign up"> Sign up</button>
                    <br>

            </form>

        </div>


            

        <!--Login form-->

                <div class ="login">
                    
                    <form method="post" style="padding-top:5px;">
                    <label for="chk" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#2e2e2e;">Login</label><br>

                        <input style="margin:auto;" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" type="text" id="text" placeholder="Email" required=""><br><br>
                        <input style="margin:auto;margin-top:-10px;" name="password" required="" value="<?php echo $password ?>" type="password" id="text" placeholder="Password"><br>

                        <button type="submit" id="button2" value="Log in">Login</button>
                        <br><br><br>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>


    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


> <?php 

session_start();

    include("classes/connect.php");
    include("classes/login.php");
 
    $email = "";
    $password = "";
    
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {


        $login = new Login();
        $result = $login->evaluate($_POST);
        
        if($result != "")
        {

            echo "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:12px;color:white;background-color:grey;'>";
            echo "<br>The following errors occured:<br><br>";
            echo $result;
            echo "</div>";
        }else
        {

            header("Location:" .ROOT. "profile");
            die;
        }
 

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
    }
    

> <?php 

    include("classes/connect.php");
    include("classes/signup.php");

    $first_name = "";
    $last_name = "";
    $gender = "";
    $email = "";

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {


        $signup = new Signup();
        $result = $signup->evaluate($_POST);
        
        if($result != "")
        {

            echo "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:12px;color:white;background-color:grey;'>";
            echo "<br>The following errors occured:<br><br>";
            echo $result;
            echo "</div>";
        }else
        {

            header("Location: " .ROOT."profile");
            die;
        }
 

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

    }

?>
```

не подскажете как сделать так чтобы при нажатии button воспроизводился нужный php обработчик? В отдельности работает отлично, но я не знаю как сделать на одной странице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в каждую форму **input** с **type="hidden**" **name="query_type**" (можно любое имя) и **value="login**" для авторизации, а для регистрации **value="signup**".
Каждый обработчик php оберните в условие  if(isset($_POST["query_type"]) && $_POST["query_type"] == "login") {...} для авторизации. Такое же условие для регистрации только вместо **login** укажите **signup**